# Is it possible to make services running on local server reachable for public?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, qnap

I'm running a local QNAP NAS server and a remote server which is hosted at a public provider (bare metal kubernetes cluster).

I would like to run some services on my nas server, which should be reachable over the internet. For example I want to run an object storage like minio - or something like that.
But my problem is, the IP of the NAS server is changing from time to time as it is using my private internet connection. I would like to make it reachable over minio.my-domain.com.

I need some ideas how I could handle this problem. I'm also running a remote bare metal kubernetes cluster, which handles the certificates for my webapps. So is it technically possible to use this server to reach my local server over public internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use service as Dynamic DNS which will provide your IP to DNS provider each time it change. You can find [here](http://qnapsupport.net/set-up-ddns-service-for-remote-internet-access-to-qnap-nas/) the QNAP support page about this service.

Also you can consult QNAP [doc page](https://docs.qnap.com/operating-system/qts/4.5.x/en-us/GUID-607EA316-9F47-40EA-82CA-5B2877712F44.html).

Comment: As I'm running also a "public" server, wouldn't it be possible to use an own service / script for this? Then I wouldn't need a third party service... Also I need to use a own domain.

Comment: @user3142695, yes, you can, but probably you should build own solution.

Comment: My problem is just the starting point for my research. What structure do I need where? Something like a reverse-proxy nginx on the remote server or is it possible to use a kubernetes service? what about the local nas server? How to update the IP, which gets send to the server?

Comment: @user3142695, on external machine install DNS with small TTL, somehow ping external from NAS, get external to recognize the IP and update it in DNS. About NAS - just set NAT on your router of the ports you use.